# Federation servers and address binding

Tags: federation

I was exploring on fed servers and understood that

- They are servers which host Stellar.toml file on their /.well-known/stellar.toml path
- This server keeps the binding of selected username and Stellar notwork address.
- When a transaction request is being made on any Fed address then Protocol 1st resolves the Binded address and then execute the transaction

If my understanding is correct on above (Please mark in case of any mis information mentioned above)

Question

1 - Who are authorised to host these servers

2 - Data hosted on these servers are centralized on Decentralized

3 - if Centralized then there should a risk of single point of failure

4 - This whole concept looks like a Virtual address concept (currently being used in India, where we can create virtual readable address and link those with our bank account and send transactions)

Regards

Comment: This is four questions.  Please post them separately, otherwise this is likely to be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Federation servers do not host `/.well-known/stellar.toml`. Though this file may exist on the same domain, and often does, it does not have to. The well-known stellar file will define the location of a federation server.

A federation server will resolve federated addresses to stellar addresses.

The network expects resolved addresses. Clients who wish to support federated addresses must undertake their own resolution before calling any endpoint on the network, including submitting transactions.

Anybody can host a federation server. Such a server is only responsible for resolving names for domains that point to it. It's not like DNS, where the servers are connected and propagate data. Federation servers are simple, stand-alone web apps for resolving federated addresses.

The authority of a federation server is provided by the well-known toml for a given domain. For example:

1. You want to resolve the address `pippin*hobbiton.org`
2. You look up `hobbtion.org/.well-known/stellar.toml` and find `FEDERATION_SERVER=https://openup.itsthefeds.io/resolve`.
3. You look up `https://openup.itsthefeds.io/resolve?q=pippin*hobbiton.org&type=id` and the JSON document returned should have the account address.

That federation server is given the authority to resolve addresses for `hobbiton.org` because the well-known toml file for that domain points to it.